# IIS deployemet on WIndows7

Tags: iis

While trying to deploy an ASP.NET MVC3 locally on my IIS7 , I'm facing this exception :
The login failed.
Login failed for user 'AUTORITE NT\IUSR'.

I'm using anonymous authentication for this site since I couldn't find windows integrated authentication on the IIS installed on my PC.

Any Ideas...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the identity under which the application pool of your site is running to an user of *Administrators* group.